# How do I get my discord bot to check if a member has a role?

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm making a discord bot and there's a command where I want only admins to be able to use, but when I try to check if the user has a role, it says that it can't read the property 'roles' of undefined. Here's the code I'm using

```
if(command === '!cmd') {
        if(message.author.id != ownerid || !message.member.roles.has(370565560972476437)) {
            messagesend("YOU ARE NOT ALLOWED TO USE THIS COMMAND\nTHIS IS YOUR ONLY WARNING")
            console.log(message.author);
        } else if(message.author.id === ownerid || message.member.roles.has("370565560972476437") || message.member.roles.some(r=>["admin"].includes(r.name))) {
            var messageArrray = messageArray.slice(1,messageArray.length)
            let evalStr = ""
            for(let element of messageArrray){
                evalStr += element + " "
            }
            console.log(evalStr);
            eval(evalStr)
            message.delete()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
if (message.guild.members.get(message.author.id).roles.exists('name','ROLENAME'){
///Code here
}
```

Thats all.